# Rhino shell read password

Tags: rhino

I would like to ask for a password in Rhino shell. I tried with what seems the obvious way:

```
function readPsw1(){
  var console = System.console();
  psw = console.readPassword("Password: ");
  return psw; 
}
```

But I cannot read more than 1 char. So I jumped to Scanner...

```
function readPsw2(){
    var scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    print("Enter password : ");
    var psw = sc.nextLine();
    sc.reset();
    return psw;
}
```

JS> psw = readPsw2() -> 1st call, I have press enter twice to get password.

JS> psw = readPsw2() -> 2nd call, first char ends reading. Then it works as first time.

Not very satisfying! What do I miss in both cases?

I also tried with jline-1.0.0 (ConsoleReader) which works fine. But (there is a but!) it doesn't work inside a Thread/spawn? spawn(readPsw2) doesn't work as expected (by me).